# Unable to set height as a percentage

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to amend the height of a footer using below css. If I set the height using pixels it will resize to the correct amount of pixels(eg height : 100px;). Setting a percentage value  as below does not seem to work. I just want to set the footer to be a percentage height of the entire screen height, so as to cater for differing screen heights. Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Here is the code I'm using : :

```
.ui-page .ui-footer .ui-navbar a {
    height : 60%;
}

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/view" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">View</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/add" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid"
                        class="ui-btn-active">Add</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/edit" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Edit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Percentage heights only work if the parent element has a set height.

Comment: @tim peterson HTML posted in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jQuery Mobile specific answer for ya'.

If you want to alter the height of the footer, then I suggest targeting the footer with your CSS rather than targeting some descentant element of the footer:

```
​.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-footer {
    height : 30%;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/csKtX/1/ (make sure to see the **update** below)

- `.ui-mobile` is applied to the HTML element when jQuery Mobile initializes.
- `.ui-page` is applied to any initialized pseudo-page.
- `.ui-footer` is applied to any initialized footer

## Update

I pasted your footer code into my JSFiddle and found-out that the `navbar` widget does not take the height of it's container (most likely your initial issue anyhow...). Here's the fix for jQuery Mobile 1.1.0:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-footer > div,/*navbar container*/
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-footer ul,/*list-item container*/
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-footer ul li,/*list-items*/
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-footer ul li a/*individual buttons*/ {
    height : 100%;
}​
```

This applies `100%` height to all the necessary elements in the footer so all the descendant elements take-on all the usable space possible.

And the new demo: http://jsfiddle.net/csKtX/2/

Answer (score 3):

You need to first set

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will allow you to set percentage heights on any elements that are direct children of `body`.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/w7mMZ/

Answer (score 0):

Add **display: block** property, maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it won't work on an anchor element `<a>`,
because it seems that you are quoting that, my advise would be to make a `<div>` and set that to the correct height.

I hope this helped..